# Rectangle shape in drawable how to give color to particular side

Tags: android, xml

In Imageview I have given given a background and that background is working fine in many devices but in Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 it is not working. What is the issue?

Main.xml

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBottomDevices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/shape_rectangle"/>
```

@res/drawable/shape_rectangle.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item  android:bottom="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid
            android:color="#00666666"/>

        <size
            android:width="80dp"
            android:height="80dp"/>
        <stroke
            android:width="10dp"
            android:color="@color/ripple_divider" />
    </shape>
</item>



<item   android:gravity="right">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <size android:width="10dp" android:height="6dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/ripple_black" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

When I comment that gravity right in shape_rectangle is creating problem because i have to give a color to particular side.

If any alternate answer is there to design a rectangle which is having color to particular right side.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivBottomDevices"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_rectangle"/>
```